# After trying to install an extension I cannot open website

Tags: magento-1.9, extensions, compiler

I tried to install the **Inchoo Social Connect** extension. I enabled compiler and merged all the files from zip with my current files in `httpdocs`.

This is how the website looks like now :
[image: website]

I have deleted all the files I have copied without any success.

Answer (score 0):

1) Make sure that you remove all the files module, `app/code/the code pool {local or comunity}/your module`. Also don't forget : `app/etc/modules/Namespace_Module.xml` because if this file is always present and the active tag is true `<active>true</active>` it bug your site. So put it to false or remove it completely.

2) Clear your Magento cache

3) Restart your server.